# How to read elements of a tensor in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I am trying to read elements of a tensor in tensorflow (V 2.6.0). For that, I have tried many methods but none of them worked for me.

Let say we want to access the elements of a.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
import numpy as np

a = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

First I tried

```
a.numpy()
```

it returned the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

After that I tried:

```
np.array(a)
```

the error

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (Reshape_5:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported
```

Last:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import get_session
a.eval(session=K.get_session())


AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras.backend' has no attribute 'get_session'
```

Comment: is there a reason why you are forcing tf 1 instead of using tf 2?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to read elements of a tensor in Tensorflow 2+.

1. Remove  `tf.disable_v2_behavior()`

> ```
> import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
> a = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
> print(a.numpy())
> ```

2. Use session

> ```
> import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
>
> tf.disable_v2_behavior()
>
> a = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
> with tf.Session() as sess:
>     print(sess.run(a))
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You are disabling tensorflow 2 with `tf.disable_v2_behavior()`

In tensorflow v1 you cannot access a tensor out of a session. Therefore you can't call `a.numpy()`

I suggest you either enable v2 or to evaluate your tensor in v1, you have to enter a session:

```py
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    print(a.eval())
# Output:
# [[1 2 3]
#  [4 5 6]]
```

Comment: It works, but not when I do tf.quantize before. Example t = tf.constant([[1.5,1.445,1.66], [1.255,1.44999,1.5111]])
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:  
  print(q.eval())

Comment: It returns: AttributeError: 'QuantizeV2' object has no attribute 'eval'. Thank you in advance